# Errors after closing and opening project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Almost always when I close a project in Visual Studio, it almost alwyas have these types of errors (written down below) when I open the project again, even if it didn`t have any errors when I closed the program. Anyone who knows why this happens and how I could fix it?

Error   CS0101  The namespace 'uppdrag_2.cs' already contains a definition for 'Program'

Error   CS0101  The namespace 'uppdrag_2.cs' already contains a definition for 'SecondClass'

Error   CS0111  Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Main' with the same parameter types

Error   CS0111  Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Newcustomer' with the same parameter types

Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.Newcustomer()' and 'Program.Newcustomer()'

Thank you in advance!
//Johanna

Comment: The solution work? Have you tried a Clean All and Rebuild All operation?

Comment: If I cklick on run it sais that "There where build errors, would you like to continue and run the last succesfull build?"

Comment: What do do you mean by "Clean all and Rebuild All operation?" (Sorry if it is a stupid question! but I`m very new to programming)